# JSON.Net equivalent of Jackson's @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)

Tags: json, jackson, json.net

Is there any setting for JSON.net which is equivalent to @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)?

Either attributes for class or global settings is fine.

Thanks very much.

I wanna ask about this is because, when developing an application at very early stage, the data structure may change quite often, deletion of a field will cause deserialization error when web client send the request of older version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Json.Net works that way by default.  In other words, if there is a property in the JSON for which there is no corresponding member defined in the target class for deserialization, that property is ignored; it does *not* cause an error.  (There is a setting to turn on errors for missing members, if you need that later; see the `MissingMemberHandling` setting in the [documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationSettings.htm#MissingMemberHandling).)